# Remove Options From Select from variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jQuery I have cached my dropdownlist like so:

```
var myDDL = $("#MyDropDownList");
```

I need to know how to remove options from `myDDL`.  This question has been asked but it is done like this:

```
$('#optExample option').remove();
```

How do I do this from a variable?

I have tried doing `myDDL.remove()`, but this removes the entire DDL from my view.  I want the DDL, just without options.

Comment: @chsdk that works! charlietfl responded to me before you, so I accept his answer, but I did upvote your answer.  For some reason.. someone downvoted it.. wasn't me though haha

Comment: No problem anyway, they don't downvote wrong answers but only right ones that can be a threat.

Comment: @chsdk I have had that happen to me.  Kinda petty honestly, but oh well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `find()` or `children()`:

```
myDDL.find('option').remove();

myDDL.children().remove():
```

Or just use `empty()` to remove everything inside an element

```
myDDL.empty()
```

Answer (score 2):

Well simply use jquery [**.empty()**](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) method:

```
myDDL.empty();
```

**Demo:**

```js
var myDDL = $("#MyDropDownList");
myDDL.empty();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="MyDropDownList">
  <option>test</option>
  <option>test</option>
  <option>test</option>
  <option>test</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call `.remove()` on your reference.

```js
var ddl = $("#MyDropDownList");
ddl.remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="MyDropDownList">
  <option>test</option>
  <option>test</option>
  <option>test</option>
  <option>test</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I have tried this.  It removes my entire DDL. The DDL just disappears from the view.